# Erro de ponteiro em um método de preencher tabela

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, nullpointerexception, awt

Aparentemente é pra estar certo, porém quando mando rodar sai os seguintes erros:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at bibl.PesquisaSimpl.preencheTabela(PesquisaSimpl.java:188)
    at bibl.PesquisaSimpl.<init>(PesquisaSimpl.java:25)
    at bibl.Bibl.bConsultaSimplActionPerformed(Bibl.java:241)
    at bibl.Bibl.access$400(Bibl.java:12)
    at bibl.Bibl$5.actionPerformed(Bibl.java:100)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Não achei o problema, será que alguém pode me ajudar?

Esse é o código:

```
package bibl;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author Kauan 
 */
public class PesquisaSimpl extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private BiblCadastro cadastro = new BiblCadastro();
BdBibl bd;
    /**
     * Creates new form PesquisaSimpl
     */
    public PesquisaSimpl() {
        initComponents();
preencheTabela();
bd = new BdBibl();
setTitle("SIGE - Módulo Biblioteca [Consulta de Livros]");
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        tTitulo = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        tAutor = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        tEditora = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        tCSimpl = new javax.swing.JTable();
        bSair = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Título");

        tTitulo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                tTituloActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel2.setText("Autor");

        jLabel3.setText("Editora");

        jLabel4.setText("Obs.:Preencha o espaço e pressione ENTER.");

        tCSimpl.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "CDD/Cutter", "Título", "Autor", "Local", "Editora", "Ano", "Situação"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tCSimpl);

        bSair.setText("Sair");
        bSair.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                bSairActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(tTitulo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 84, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(tAutor, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 87, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(tEditora, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 120, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(bSair))
                            .addComponent(jLabel4))
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(16, 16, 16)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(tTitulo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(tAutor, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(tEditora, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(bSair))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 282, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void bSairActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
this.dispose();
    }                                     

    private void tTituloActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                       
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int tecla = e.getKeyCode();
    if (tecla == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        }

    }


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PesquisaSimpl.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    //</editor-fold>

        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new PesquisaSimpl().setVisible(true);
        });
    }private void formWindowGainedFocus(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt ) {
    preencheTabela();
}

  private void preencheTabela(){
        DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) tCSimpl.getModel();
        int i = modelo.getRowCount();
        while (i --> 0) {
            modelo.removeRow(i);
        }
List c = bd.pesquisa(tTitulo.getText());
 for (Iterator it = c.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
 it.next();        
        modelo.addRow(new Object[]{ cadastro.getCdd(), cadastro.getTitulo(), cadastro.getAutor(), cadastro.getLocal(), cadastro.getEditora(), cadastro.getAno(), cadastro.getSituacao() });
    }
  }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton bSair;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField tAutor;
    private javax.swing.JTable tCSimpl;
    private javax.swing.JTextField tEditora;
    private javax.swing.JTextField tTitulo;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

E o do banco de dados:

```
package bibl;

import java.util.List;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author admin
 */
public class BdBibl extends Bd{
     public BdBibl() {
 try {
 conexao();
 } catch (Exception e) {
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro: " + e.getMessage());
 }
 } 
     public void insere(BiblCadastro b){
      String sql = "insert into b(registro,cdd,cutter,compl,compl2,titulo,autor,editora,local,ano,edicao,idioma,assunto,descricao,paginas,bibliografia,exemplar,formaaquis,dataaquis,fornecedor,tombo,situacao) values(?,?,?,?)"; 
try {
 PreparedStatement ps = getCon().prepareStatement(sql); 
 ps.setString(1, b.getRegistro()); 
 ps.setString(2, b.getCdd()); 
 ps.setString(3, b.getCutter());
 ps.setString(4, b.getCompl());
 ps.setString(5, b.getCompl2());
 ps.setString(6, b.getTitulo()); 
 ps.setString(7, b.getAutor());
 ps.setString(8, b.getEditora()); 
 ps.setString(9, b.getLocal());
 ps.setInt(10, b.getAno()); 
 ps.setString(11, b.getEdicao()); 
 ps.setString(12, b.getIdioma()); 
 ps.setString(13, b.getAssunto()); 
 ps.setString(14, b.getDescricao());
 ps.setInt(15, b.getPaginas()); 
 ps.setString(16, b.getBibliografia()); 
 ps.setString(17, b.getExemplar()); 
 ps.setString(18, b.getFormaaquis()); 
 ps.setString(19, b.getDataaquis());
 ps.setString(20, b.getFornecedor());
 ps.setInt(21, b.getTombo());
 ps.setString(22, b.getSituacao()); 
 ps.execute();
      } catch (SQLException e) {
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro SQL: " + e.getMessage());
 } 
}
     public void atualiza(BiblCadastro b){
          String sql = "update b set registro=?,cutter=?,compl=?,compl2=?,titulo=?,autor=?,editora=?,local=?,ano=?,edicao=?,idioma=?,assunto=?,descricao=?,paginas=?,bibliografia=?,exemplar=?,formaaquis=?,dataaquis=?,fornecedor=?,tombo=?,situacao=? where cdd=?"; 
try {
 PreparedStatement ps = getCon().prepareStatement(sql); 
 ps.setString(1, b.getRegistro()); 
 ps.setString(22, b.getCdd()); 
 ps.setString(2, b.getCutter());
 ps.setString(3, b.getCompl());
 ps.setString(4, b.getCompl2());
 ps.setString(5, b.getTitulo()); 
 ps.setString(6, b.getAutor());
 ps.setString(7, b.getEditora()); 
 ps.setString(8, b.getLocal());
 ps.setInt(9, b.getAno()); 
 ps.setString(10, b.getEdicao()); 
 ps.setString(11, b.getIdioma()); 
 ps.setString(12, b.getAssunto()); 
 ps.setString(13, b.getDescricao());
 ps.setInt(14, b.getPaginas()); 
 ps.setString(15, b.getBibliografia()); 
 ps.setString(16, b.getExemplar()); 
 ps.setString(17, b.getFormaaquis()); 
 ps.setString(18, b.getDataaquis());
 ps.setString(19, b.getFornecedor());
 ps.setInt(20, b.getTombo());
 ps.setString(21, b.getSituacao()); 
 ps.execute();

      } catch (SQLException e) {
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro SQL: " + e.getMessage());
 }
     }
     public BiblCadastro localiza (String cdd){
         String sql = "select * from b where cdd=?";
         BiblCadastro bibl =new BiblCadastro();
         try {
 PreparedStatement ps = getCon().prepareStatement(sql); 
ps.setString(1, cdd);
 ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(); 
 if (rs.next()) { 
bibl.setCdd(rs.getString("cdd"));
bibl.setRegistro(rs.getString("registro"));
bibl.setCutter(rs.getString("cutter"));
bibl.setCompl(rs.getString("compl"));
bibl.setCompl2(rs.getString("compl2"));
bibl.setTitulo(rs.getString("titulo"));
bibl.setAutor(rs.getString("autor"));
bibl.setEditora(rs.getString("editora"));
bibl.setLocal(rs.getString("local"));
bibl.setAno(rs.getInt("ano"));
bibl.setEdicao(rs.getString("edicao"));
bibl.setIdioma(rs.getString("idioma"));
bibl.setCdd(rs.getString("cdd"));
bibl.setAssunto(rs.getString("assunto"));
bibl.setDescricao(rs.getString("descricao"));
bibl.setPaginas(rs.getInt("paginas"));
bibl.setBibliografia(rs.getString("bibliografia"));
bibl.setExemplar(rs.getString("exemplar"));
bibl.setFormaaquis(rs.getString("formaaquis"));
bibl.setDataaquis(rs.getString("dataaquis"));
bibl.setFornecedor(rs.getString("fornecedor"));
bibl.setTombo(rs.getInt("tombo"));
bibl.setSituacao(rs.getString("situacao"));
 }
 } catch (SQLException e) {
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro SQL: " + e.getMessage());
 }
 return bibl;            
}
   /*   public List pesquisaTitulo(String busca) { 
 String sql = "select * from b where titulo like ?"; 
 List lista=new ArrayList(); 
try {
 PreparedStatement ps = getCon().prepareStatement(sql);
 ps.setString(1, "%"+busca+"%"); 
 ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
 while (rs.next()) { 
  BiblCadastro bibl = new BiblCadastro();
  bibl.setCdd(rs.getString("cdd"));
bibl.setRegistro(rs.getString("registro"));
bibl.setCutter(rs.getString("cutter"));
bibl.setCompl(rs.getString("compl"));
bibl.setCompl2(rs.getString("compl2"));
bibl.setTitulo(rs.getString("titulo"));
bibl.setAutor(rs.getString("autor"));
bibl.setEditora(rs.getString("editora"));
bibl.setLocal(rs.getString("local"));
bibl.setAno(rs.getInt("ano"));
bibl.setEdicao(rs.getString("edicao"));
bibl.setIdioma(rs.getString("idioma"));
bibl.setCdd(rs.getString("cdd"));
bibl.setAssunto(rs.getString("assunto"));
bibl.setDescricao(rs.getString("descricao"));
bibl.setPaginas(rs.getInt("paginas"));
bibl.setBibliografia(rs.getString("bibliografia"));
bibl.setExemplar(rs.getString("exemplar"));
bibl.setFormaaquis(rs.getString("formaaquis"));
bibl.setDataaquis(rs.getString("dataaquis"));
bibl.setFornecedor(rs.getString("fornecedor"));
bibl.setTombo(rs.getInt("tombo"));
bibl.setSituacao(rs.getString("situacao"));
 }
}
 catch (SQLException e) {
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro SQL: " + e.getMessage());
 }
 return lista;
}
     */
       public List pesquisa(String busca) { 
 String sql = "select * from b where cdd like ?"; 
 List lista=new ArrayList(); 
try {
 PreparedStatement ps = getCon().prepareStatement(sql);
 ps.setString(1, "%"+busca+"%"); 
 ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
 while (rs.next()) { 
  BiblCadastro bibl = new BiblCadastro();
  bibl.setCdd(rs.getString("cdd"));
bibl.setRegistro(rs.getString("registro"));
bibl.setCutter(rs.getString("cutter"));
bibl.setCompl(rs.getString("compl"));
bibl.setCompl2(rs.getString("compl2"));
bibl.setTitulo(rs.getString("titulo"));
bibl.setAutor(rs.getString("autor"));
bibl.setEditora(rs.getString("editora"));
bibl.setLocal(rs.getString("local"));
bibl.setAno(rs.getInt("ano"));
bibl.setEdicao(rs.getString("edicao"));
bibl.setIdioma(rs.getString("idioma"));
bibl.setCdd(rs.getString("cdd"));
bibl.setAssunto(rs.getString("assunto"));
bibl.setDescricao(rs.getString("descricao"));
bibl.setPaginas(rs.getInt("paginas"));
bibl.setBibliografia(rs.getString("bibliografia"));
bibl.setExemplar(rs.getString("exemplar"));
bibl.setFormaaquis(rs.getString("formaaquis"));
bibl.setDataaquis(rs.getString("dataaquis"));
bibl.setFornecedor(rs.getString("fornecedor"));
bibl.setTombo(rs.getInt("tombo"));
bibl.setSituacao(rs.getString("situacao"));
lista.add(bibl);
 }
}
 catch (SQLException e) {
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro SQL: " + e.getMessage());
 }
 return lista;
}


      /*   public List pesquisaEditora(String busca) { 
 String sql = "select * from b where editora like ?"; 
 List lista=new ArrayList(); 
try {
 PreparedStatement ps = getCon().prepareStatement(sql);
 ps.setString(1, "%"+busca+"%"); 
 ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
 while (rs.next()) { 
  BiblCadastro bibl = new BiblCadastro();
  bibl.setCdd(rs.getString("cdd"));
bibl.setRegistro(rs.getString("registro"));
bibl.setCutter(rs.getString("cutter"));
bibl.setCompl(rs.getString("compl"));
bibl.setCompl2(rs.getString("compl2"));
bibl.setTitulo(rs.getString("titulo"));
bibl.setAutor(rs.getString("autor"));
bibl.setEditora(rs.getString("editora"));
bibl.setLocal(rs.getString("local"));
bibl.setAno(rs.getInt("ano"));
bibl.setEdicao(rs.getString("edicao"));
bibl.setIdioma(rs.getString("idioma"));
bibl.setCdd(rs.getString("cdd"));
bibl.setAssunto(rs.getString("assunto"));
bibl.setDescricao(rs.getString("descricao"));
bibl.setPaginas(rs.getInt("paginas"));
bibl.setBibliografia(rs.getString("bibliografia"));
bibl.setExemplar(rs.getString("exemplar"));
bibl.setFormaaquis(rs.getString("formaaquis"));
bibl.setDataaquis(rs.getString("dataaquis"));
bibl.setFornecedor(rs.getString("fornecedor"));
bibl.setTombo(rs.getInt("tombo"));
bibl.setSituacao(rs.getString("situacao"));
 }
}
 catch (SQLException e) {
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro SQL: " + e.getMessage());
 }
 return lista;
}
       */
      public void exclui (String cdd){
           String sql = "delete from b where cdd=?"; 
try {
 PreparedStatement ps = getCon().prepareStatement(sql);
 ps.setString(1, cdd);
 ps.execute();
 } catch (SQLException e) {
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro SQL: " + e.getMessage());
 } 
      }
}
```

Comment: Pq no seu método preencheTabela o while está com while (i --> 0) ?

Comment: para remover a linha

Comment: Não tem nenhum método melhor pra remover tudo do `model`? (talvez `modelo.setRowCount(0)`) Seu loop está removendo todas as linhas uma a uma, pelo que me parece. À propósito, `i-- > 0`fica mais legível se for manter assim.